# How to get the WINDOWS USER within "EXECUTE AS OWNER"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a function which returns the WINDOWS USER (NOT the database user!) within a procedure which is "EXECUTE AS OWNER" ?

Will ORIGINAL_LOGIN() do this, or does that only return the database user ?

Consider the following situation:

- Windows Users "joe" and "anne" are part of a Active Directory Group, e.g. "PLANNERS"
- The SQL Server Database has "PLANNERS" as Server Login and as Database User.
- There is stored procedure WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER

Now, anne is logging into the SQL Database via Windows Authentification (so she is database user "PLANNERS"), and she calls the procedure. In this procedure, I want to retrieve the Windows User ("anne").

Comment: you cant see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648166/how-to-get-windows-log-in-user-name-for-a-sql-log-in-user

If the connection is made by an application you could write the nt user to the session context

Comment: In this question, he is asking for a "SQL login" user. In my case, we are logging in with Windows Authentification. I will edit the question.

Comment: In the documentation of ORIGINAL_LOGIN() it says `ORIGINAL_LOGIN returns the identity of the login that first connected to the instance of SQL Server in that session`
So this is exactly what you need
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189492(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: You can use SUSER_SNAME() which returns the login name associated with a security identification number

Comment: @deterministicFail -  Just to consider: The Windows Login is DIFFERENT to the Database Login ! I need the Windows Login!  Does ORIGINAL_LOGIN really deliver the Windows Login? Problem is, I cannot test it properly in my current environment

Answer (score 1):

ORIGINAL_LOGIN() is the correct answer.

Just needed it again ;) 
Thanks @deterministicfail