# Finding NT user (Windows login) that uses SQL Server Login

Tags: sql-server, powershell, wmi-query

As part of a security task I need to find all SQL Server logins that connect to the SQL server instance.

I create  extended event  for capture logins and filter only SQL Server logins.
The problem is that I can not tell from the SQL Server what was the NT user that was used.
Example:
From the xEvent I can see that user [sa]  logged in to the SQL server instance and I can also see this client host name.
BUT , now I would like to know what was the domain account that was logged in to the client host name and use this SQL authentication.

I understand that SQL Server can not give this information but I would like yo know if I can get this info using PowerShell maybe.
I have the host name and the SID.

I could not find a solution here :
[How to get Windows Log-in User Name for a SQL Log in User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648166/how-to-get-windows-log-in-user-name-for-a-sql-log-in-user)

Comment: Use sp_who for that

Comment: Hi Sami, I wish it was so simple . , but sp_who will not show any NT user when you log-in with SQL authentication . in fact the solution (I believe) will not come from the SQL server itself ...

Comment: I'm a little uncertain what you mean. By "NT User" are you referring to a local Windows user account that has permissions to login to SQL Server? Or an Active Directory domain user? Regardless, if you have the user account SID, you should be able to translate this into a username.

Comment: I'm looking to find the AD domain user that use for login the server (can be remote server or local server) and then use a SQL authentication to connect the SQL server .

Answer (score 3):

You do not have a SID, that is a SQL Server SID (yes, there is a such a concept).

First, the answer: you do not. If you want to prevent SQL Logins, you deactivate SQL Logins, and that should be the end of the story.

Since there is no NTLM/Kerberos exchange for a SQL Server login, there is no way to find the credentials of the process/thread that initiated a SQL Login connection. However, you do have the host from where the connection was initiated and the process ID (they are the `host_name` and `host_process_id` columns in [`sys.dm_exec_sessions`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013(v=sql.105).aspx)). Finding the credentials of the remote process is a trivial matter left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You've referenced having the SID, so if this is correct you can translate that to a user account. This works for both local users, and domain users:

```
$sid = 'S-1-5-21-3423846758-2645770820-3983523239-1001'
$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($sid)
$objUser = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
($objUser.value -split '\\')[1]
```

Note: `$objUser` will contain either the computer name (for a local account) or the domain name (for an Active Directory account), so the split is to parse out the username only.

However, I'm currently unsure how you link this to which account they're using within SQL server (using SQL authentication) - I'm not sure where you're getting the SID information from (Windows event logs? Within SQL itself?).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.
I managed to get the AD domain user by running a `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process` :

1.Find the `host_process_id and host_name using sys.dm_exec_sessions`

2.Run a PowerShell:

```
 Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -ComputerName $host_name -Filter "ProcessId = '$($host_process_id )'" | ForEach-Object { $_.GetOwner() }
```