# Retrieve Windows Login from code in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, winapi

I am just converting an MS Access database to SQL Server and have run into a couple issues around queries that use the `NetworkUsername()` API call to retrieve the current Windows username.

In SQL Server, it works fine for me to call the `SYSTEM_USER` function, as long as I'm logging into SQL Server with Windows authentication.

But the new database is setup to login to SQL Server with one generic SQL Server login, so a passthrough query will show name that as the SQL login.

Is there a way to call an API procedure from inside SQL Server stored procedure - maybe by duplicating the API function with a C routine or external call to the API?

What I used before in VBA was

```
Private Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long

Public Function NetworkUserName() As String
    Dim strBuffer As String * 255
    Dim lngBufferLength As Long
    Dim lngRet As Long
    Dim strTemp As String

    lngBufferLength = 255
    lngRet = GetUserName(strBuffer, lngBufferLength)
    NetworkUserName = Left$(strBuffer, InStr(strBuffer, Chr$(0)) - 1)
End Function
```

It looks like others have tried and maybe come close?

[Finding NT user (Windows login) that uses SQL Server Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860132/finding-nt-user-windows-login-that-uses-sql-server-login)

Comment: SQL Server doesn't know the login in name of the account that established the connection. This would be a bit of a security issue. If you want that kind of information you are going to need to use different sql accounts. Maybe using windows authentication would work in your case?

Comment: I guess I can always pass it as a parameter from MS-Access to the stored procedure.

Comment: Sure that would work.