# SQL Server: Logging database changes based on application user

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ado, audit

I want to accomplish that when say user "123" logs into the application and then does changes to data in the database, that this change will be logged into a mirror table with "123" in an extra column.

The idea was to write a trigger that saves "inserted" or "deleted" in the mirror table, but the problem is that the application always uses the same database user, so I need to connect the application user with the database somehow.

So my idea was to save @@SPID with the application user into a table when a user logs into the application. Unfortunately, I figured that @@SPID can be different for every query, even if I use the same ADOConnection class.

I can't use application name or host name either, because it could be that different users on the same server start the same application and I need to be able to differentiate the changes the first user did from the changes the second user did.

The application is very large, so updating every query to manually log changes is not an option right now.

Is there any other solution for this problem?

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648166/how-to-get-windows-log-in-user-name-for-a-sql-log-in-user

Comment: Are your usrs domain users? Do you want to know the domain account of a user that logins to server using SQL Server login (via your application)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution for it myself now: Use host_process_id.

Basically when an application user logs in, you can connect him to the host_process_id in the dm_exec_sessions system table. Then when a trigger runs, you can get the host_process_id from @@SPID to find out which user did the change.

Even if @@SPID changes, host_process_id remains the same, but it has a different value when the same application runs on the same server twice.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to is to capture user information in each table with respect to the record modified/inserted/deleted. When user is making changes to the record, update his details like ID into the column like 'LastModifiedBy'. This should solve the problem of capturing the user information.-- As I don't see any other possible way for this

The simple solution to audit logging is to enable SQL Change Data Capture on your database table. It will take care of logging the audit information into system tables created by it. But please note that CDC has a retention period, it is usually 3 days. So every three days the data will be wiped of from the CDC tables. You may want to explore an opportunity to disable the cleaning so that you can permanently store the info in CDC tables OR simply write a .Net windows service or a SSIS package to pull info from CDC tables and push to another Audit database.